# How to display youtube video id with this javascript

Tags: javascript, youtube

I'm using [this javascript](http://www.yvoschaap.com/ytpage/ytembed.js) to display youtube search results on my page.

This is the section from the code that displays title, description and so on...

```
li.innerHTML = '<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
<tr><td valign="top" rowspan="2"></td>
<td valign="top"><h3>'+entry.title+'</h3><span>'+this.formatDescription(entry.description)+'</span></td>
<td valign="top" style="width: 150px" class="meta">
<div>From: <a href="http://www.youtube.com/profile?user='+entry.uploader+'">'+entry.uploader+'</a></div><div>Views: '+entry.viewCount+'</div><div>'+this.formatRating(entry.rating,entry.ratingCount)+' ratings</div>Time: '+this.formatDuration(entry.duration)+'</td></tr></table>';
```

How can I add `'+ytPlayerParams.videoId+'` or `'+data.id+'` or something else from the javascript, so that it would display the youtube video ID `http://www.youtube.com/embed/...`

Answer (score 0):

```
li.innerHTML = '<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
  <tr><td valign="top" rowspan="2"></td>
    <td valign="top">
       <h3>'+entry.title+'</h3
       <span>'+this.formatDescription(entry.description)+'</span>
    </td>
    <td valign="top" style="width: 150px" class="meta">
      <div>From: <a href="http://www.youtube.com/profile?user='+entry.uploader+'">'+entry.uploader+'</a></div>
      <div>ID: '+entry.id+'</div><div>Views: '+entry.viewCount+'</div><div>'+this.formatRating(entry.rating,entry.ratingCount)+' ratings</div>
      Time: '+this.formatDuration(entry.duration)+'
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>';
```

I added a div for id which will give the unique video id